# Errors while running bibliography \harvardurl

Tags: bibliographies

I've been working on this Latex file for quite a while now. I'm using texstudio on mac, exporting a bib file from Zotero and inserting it into my Latex document using the normal \bibliography{list}

Throughout writing this document, I constantly build and view the document. That way I know the document runs without errors. I don't know how or why but when I ran the texstudio, like I always do, this time I got errors.

- line 176: File ended while scanning use of \harvardurl. \bibliography{list}
- line 178: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}

And then many "undefined citations" warnings, which results in ? instead of the usual reference citation (author,year). Not all references are like that, maybe about half and they're randomly distributed across the document.

I have tried running the document without the text that I have most recently added. Also tried to re-add the bib file.

I have tried googling for this error, but none seem to be useful, as the error occurred after I had added a bit of normal text, no Latex code.

**Any help with regards to what the errors mean or how to source the errors myself are highly appreciated!**

I've tried to add my bib file here, but am not allowed.

Comment: Wlcome to Tex. Could you add a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)? It would help to find the problem.

Comment: Try to delete the temporary files and recompile from scratch. If that fails check the URLs in your `.bib` file, does one of them contain a `%`? Can you show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces the problem, please?

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Did you check your URLs for `%`?

Comment: @moewe I just checked the bib file for % in the URL. I have found one and this was one of the latest ones that I had added to the document. I'll take out this reference for now and attempt to run the document without it. I'll report back. RE a MWE, I don't know how to do so, because I can't upload the bibliography because it contains too many URL's as per stackexchange guidelines for beginners.

Comment: The point of an MWE is that you try to find the few references that actually cause the problem and cut all of those you don't need to demonstrate the problem. Normally even large `.bib` files can be brought back to one or two problematic entries.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426975/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close off this thread. As @moewe mentioned, the `.bib` file had several `%` in it, which caused the Latex to skip over several other references.