# File ended wile scanning use of \harvardurl. \bibliography{thesis_references}

Tags: preamble, compilation-error

I have compilation errors in my document which seem to be very similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9445/urls-break-compilation) question. The error message:

```
"File ended wile scanning use of \harvardurl. \bibliography{thesis_references}
```

The problem is with my preamble - might be conflicting packages. The full preamble is getting quite chunky now but these are the components which I think are relevant to the problem:

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% use harvard style referencing
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

%% redefine uarvardurl command as in texexchange anwer
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \bibliography{thesis_references}
\end{document}
```

The problem doesn't occur if I delete my `bbl` file and change the referencing style to `abbrvnat`. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I assume one of your ULRs contains a `%`, but without a `.bib` file that is just guesswork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to say without seeing the `bib` file and the used packages, but it looks like there are special characters in a URL, most likely a `%`.

You probably use the `natbib` package instead of `harvard`. Then you can fix this by allowing `\url` to change the catcodes while reading it's argument.
Just change your `\harvardurl` command to

```
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}{\textbf{URL:} \url}
```

Comment: It worked! You have been most helpful, thank you.